# Mail function - change SMTP relay

Tags: php, smtp

I use PHP's `mail` function to send emails from my server, which currently also handles mail. However, I would like PHP to start sending messages through a different SMTP relay, not the server it's running on. I checked out `php.ini`, and it appears that it is only possible to specify a different relay on a Windows PC, whilst my server is running OS X Snow Leopard. Is it possible to change the relay settings? Ideally, I wouldn't want to incorporate anything new into my PHP code, as I use the `mail` function all over the place.

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) may have more insight than Stack Overflow.

Comment: afaik you are out of luck with your mail() method. You will need to use a php-class acting like a SMTP-Client (eg. swiftmailer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without either setting up a sendmail alternative on your server that routes mail through SMTP, or much much easier, using a library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html).

PHP does not have the capability to use an external SMTP server built in (Unless you are on a Windows platform).

Comment: If you do a find and replace on your code to replace mail(etc) with swiftmail(etc) and write a wrapper function to send with swiftmail you should be able to do this with minimal friction.

Comment: Quick question... how would the `mail` function work if my server didn't act as a mail relay? How exactly does it function? What does it plug into?